# How to adjust the background to the object

Tags: inkscape, background-removal

[image: object with green background]

I want to adjust the green background, so it fits to the object in the front.
When I try path->difference the two, it gives me the wrong result
I'm using Inkscape.

Comment: You're probably running into difficulties because your brown shape isn't a solid object. There are gaps in the borders that extend the full of the line in some areas and Inkscape can't know that you want these gaps to be treated as if they weren't there. If you have a copy of the brown shape with solid borders (before you applied the wood grain effect), try working with that. The Division or Exclusion command might get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks @z3z, I used a copy of the shape and divison and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use Photoshop cause is more specified in this kind of retouches 
So you can open your image in PS and select the green color after you can separate the background from the green and finally change what you want of color.